# Why is keyup event not triggering correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use an jquery keyup event. But i can't get it to trigger correctly. It seems to only hit then i use the mouse to click out side the input field. I can't find why it won't work correctly.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control requiredField validateField translateString " id="ReportInternalOrderTxt" data-isvalid="false">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).off("keyup", "#ReportInternalOrderTxt").on("keyup", "#ReportInternalOrderTxt", function (e) {
     var result = parseInt($("#ReportInternalOrderTxt").val());
     $("#ReportInternalOrderTxt").attr("data-isvalid", (typeof result === "number" && (result % 1) === 0) && result > 0);
});
```

Comment: I have a feeling you are talking about the validation not triggering and not the keypress.

Comment: You can use jQuery validate for your function... it is super

Answer (score 1):

I think you just confused everyone thinking that the keyup was not working when in reality you are talking about the validation not trigger until you blur the element. That is because the validaion is waiting for onchange to fire which happens when blur occurs. So you need to trigger it manually after setting the data attribute.

```
$(document).off("keyup.numValidate").on("keyup.numValidate", "#ReportInternalOrderTxt", function (e)
    var textbox = $(this);
    var result = parseInt(textbox.val(), 10);
    textbox.attr("data-isvalid", (typeof result === "number" && (result % 1) === 0) && result > 0);
    textbox.change(); // or textbox.trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
 $('#ReportInternalOrderTxt').keyup(function(){
     //Your code
 });
```

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Hi, i have just tried it and still the same problem.

Comment: Not possible, if you have unique ids. Do you have a document ready?

Comment: Wrong Wrong Wrong.... -1...FROM THE DOCS: `This method is a shortcut for .on( "keyup", handler )`. You are just attaching the keyup event directly onto the element....

Comment: What you are expecting? This function ntriggers if the user makes a keyup (Keyboard) in a input field.... If you want to trigger the click in the box you have to do focus()

Comment: LOOK to the right, there is the `on()`. The OP is removing the event and readding it.

Comment: I use the "style" at the top every time and it works PERFECTLY (it is as in the docs of jQuery). If he want to trigger the keyup event on THIS element it works PERFECTLY. over and out...